# Excel VBA : .Range method or data member not found

Tags: vba, excel

I having issue with the code below but when i try the `Set FoundCell = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=StartDate1, lookat:=xlWhole)` in a different forms it works fine but only with this new forms is not working.

the below is the complete code that is having issue :

I there a ay for me to compare the Startdate to find the range?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim wsReport As Sheets
Dim objEachSheet As Sheets
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim iRow As Long
Dim xRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim Rw As Long
Dim ERW As Long
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim FoundName As String
Dim StartDate1 As String
Dim LastDate1 As String
Dim StartArray As Variant
Dim EndArray As Variant
Dim FoundArray As Variant
Dim iColumn As Long

StartDate1 = StartDate.Value
LastDate1 = LastDate.Value

StartArray() = Split(StartDate1, "-")
EndArray() = Split(LastDate1, "-")   

x = 1
y = 20

Set wsReport = Sheets("MonthlyReport") 'changed

    For Each objEachSheet In Sheets

        With objEachSheet

            Set FoundCell = .Range("A:A").Find(what:=StartDate1, lookat:=xlWhole)

            If Not FoundCell Is Nothing And objEachSheet.Name <> "Stock" And objEachSheet.Name <> "MachineSales" And objEachSheet.Name <> "AddStock" And objEachSheet.Name <> "Balance" Then
             iRow = objEachSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
             Rw = FoundCell.Row
             FoundName = objEachSheet.Name
             FoundArray() = Split(objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 1), "-")
            End If

             For x = 1 To 21
                If objEachSheet.Name = wsReport.Cells(1, x) Then
                  iColumn = x
                End If
             Next x

             For xRow = 0 To iRow
                If FoundArray(0) >= StartArray(0) And FoundArray(0) <= EndArray(0) And FoundArray(1) = StartArray(1) And FoundArray(2) = StartArray(2) Then
                Select Case FoundArray(0)
                    Case "01"
                        wsReport.Cells(2, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "02"
                        wsReport.Cells(3, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "03"
                        wsReport.Cells(4, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "04"
                        wsReport.Cells(5, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "05"
                        wsReport.Cells(6, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "06"
                        wsReport.Cells(7, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "07"
                        wsReport.Cells(8, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "08"
                        wsReport.Cells(9, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "09"
                        wsReport.Cells(10, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "10"
                        wsReport.Cells(11, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "11"
                        wsReport.Cells(12, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "12"
                        wsReport.Cells(13, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "13"
                        wsReport.Cells(14, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "14"
                        wsReport.Cells(15, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "15"
                        wsReport.Cells(16, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "16"
                        wsReport.Cells(17, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "17"
                        wsReport.Cells(18, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "18"
                        wsReport.Cells(19, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "19"
                        wsReport.Cells(20, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "20"
                        wsReport.Cells(21, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "21"
                        wsReport.Cells(22, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "22"
                        wsReport.Cells(23, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "23"
                        wsReport.Cells(24, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "24"
                        wsReport.Cells(25, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "25"
                        wsReport.Cells(26, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "26"
                        wsReport.Cells(27, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "27"
                        wsReport.Cells(28, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "28"
                        wsReport.Cells(29, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "29"
                        wsReport.Cells(30, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "30"
                        wsReport.Cells(31, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                    Case "31"
                        wsReport.Cells(32, iColumn) = objEachSheet.Cells(Rw, 5)
                End Select

             Next xRow

        End With


    Next objEachSheet

    End Sub
```

*button code*

```
    Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Unload Me
    End Sub
```

Comment: Should be `StartArray = Split(StartDate1, "-")` and `EndArray = Split(LastDate1, "-")` .

Answer (score 4):

Change this:

```
Dim wsReport As Sheets
```

to this:

```
Dim wsReport As Worksheet
```

do the same for `objEachSheet`

You need to declare them as singular worksheet objects. Sheets is a collection.

Also, be explicit in which workbook you are cycling through with something like:

```
For Each objEachSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
```

You could use `Activeworkbook.Sheets` but that includes charts, which don't have ranges to search through.

Comment: Ow my bad >.<~ it works but now i can't split my string to array... tried split and also StringToArray but failed to ><

Comment: Programming is an endless series of questions. Sounds like maybe I answered this one. You know where to ask the next :).

Comment: okay Thanks alot :D ~ lucky to found this place and have helped me alot :D